# Post-Beginner courses that delve into making more complex machine learning systems (computer vision, genetic algorithms, text/image generation)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I took an ML course in college that covered basically the same stuff as Andrew Ng's Coursera course (but also included a little more math and proofs than Ng's course). I just took Ng's course as a refresher and now I don't know where to go.

I would like to learn to do cool stuff like make a model which learns to play a video game by itself. I find genetic algorithms really interesting but have zero clue how they work. For instance this video i keep coming back to these videos and wondering how it works.

[Genetic Algorithm Learns to fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2t77mQmJiY)

[MarI/O neural network playing videogame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44)

The other thing that interests me is computer vision and natural language stuff. The Recurrent Neural Network that learns to make [new magic cards by itself is really amazing to me](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/articles/view/scienceandtech/14276-Magic-The-Gathering-Cards-Made-by-Artificial-Intelligence).

But both the video game genetic algorithms and recurrent neural networks sound way to complicated. In addition i don't have an ultra-powerful computer to train a model on and i also don't know where to get the data to train.

Basically i am wondering how to learn these more advanced topics and how people come up with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links you posted are about genetic algorithms. About them, and how the MarI/O game works) you can read the book Ai Techniques For Game Programming, in which the algorithm NEAT is used to construct AI games. It also have a implementation in a self driving car on my [github](https://github.com/Lucas001/NEAT-for-autonomous-car).

There are also two more important links you should read. About the use of neural network to learn Atari Games [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf), and its use in gridworld [here](http://outlace.com/Reinforcement-Learning-Part-3/). This algorithm is the state-of-the-art nowadays.

If you are interested on agents learning, as your description, you also must read the Sutton [here](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/the-book.html). Reinforcement Learning is what you are looking for.